# I have domain parked for the future use. However, someone register Trademark with the same as Domain name

Tags: domains, legal, trademark

I bought the domain 2 yrs before someone registered TM with exact the  name. I do not have plan to use the domain in the nar future.
Am I still OK to sell  to the company or it is not legal?

I am getting buisiness emails of the company. Should I forward those to them?

I am concern about possible issue.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for trademark varies in different countries.

Generally speaking, if the domain was registered before the trademark then you shouldn't have any issue.

But to maintain your ownership in future, you may need to contact local IP and seek further clarification.